# Share dll between WP7 and WP8 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Usually it is [recommended to](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Maintaining_a_WP7_and_WP8_version_of_a_same_application) have two projects for both wp7 and wp8 platforms. Wp7 project contains .cs and .xaml files, and WP8 project contains links to that files.

I think that there is no reason to compile non-platform specific business logic code twice, since it can be referenced to WP8 project.

I'm thinking about following solution structure:

- Business logic dll compiled for wp7 (not a PCL)
- UI comliled for wp8
- UI comliled for wp7

Such application can be compiled and I can deploy it to device/emulator.

The question is: will this app pass certification in Windows phone store? Or it is necessary to recompile shared dll?

**UPD:**
My crazy idea was born after this steps:

1. Create new WP7 app (**WindowsPhoneApplication1**)
2. Create class library targeted to WP7 (**WindowsPhoneClassLibrary1**) Use it in **WindowsPhoneApplication1**
3. Use Upgrade to WP8 menu. **WindowsPhoneApplication1** will be updated to WP8, but the referenced project will be still targeted to WP7!
4. Such app can be deployed to WP8 devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Claus,
I made some research, and it looks like the answer is - you can use such solution.

I didn't find related information in documentation, but here is a proof from one of MSFT tech. evangelists from Netherlands: [link to blogpost](http://blog.rajenki.com/2012/12/how-to-add-windows-phone-8-builds-to-your-existing-apps/)

> The basic idea is to move all our code that can be used from both our existing Windows Phone 7 app as well as the Windows Phone 8 build, which we will add soon, to a Common project in the solution. The bad thing about this approach is that we have to create the Common project as a Windows Phone 7 class library, which will be used in our Windows Phone 8 build. I haven’t really noticed any negative impact of this decision in my existing apps, but note that you will be referencing a Windows Phone 7 library in your Windows Phone 8 build.

So it is a possible, but not the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you use a Portable Class Library, you'll need to have separate project files, and compile separately for WP7 and WP8.

Comment: Claus thank you for the answer. But could you comment the update in my question? Will that simple app be rejected?

Comment: The manifest files will be different, and hence either or will be rejected.